# references to learn the general theory Lie $\infty$-groupoids and Lie $\infty$-algebroids

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, lie-groupoids, lie-algebroids

Kirill Mackenzie has a book on the general theory of Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids.

Is there such a reference for the general theory of Lie $\infty$-groupoids and Lie $\infty$-algebroids; that covers some of the following topics:

1. Definition(s) and examples of Lie $\infty$-groupoids, Lie $\infty$-algebroids.
2. Some constructions of new Lie $\infty$-groupoids from old Lie $\infty$-groupoids; similarly for Lie $\infty$-algebroids
3. assigning Lie $\infty$-algebroid for a Lie $\infty$-groupoid
4. some details about ''integration of Lie $\infty$-algebroid'' to give a Lie $\infty$-groupoids.

Or, as a first step, reference for the general theory of Lie $2$-groupoids and Lie $2$-algebroids.

Answer (score 3):

There is no introductory book on Lie ∞-groupoids and ∞-algebroids analogous to Mackenzie's book.
The only book-length treatment that covers these subjects is Urs Schreiber's [Differential cohomology in a cohesive ∞-topos](https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/differential+cohomology+in+a+cohesive+topos).

Otherwise, the material is scattered over many sources.

Some annotated lists of references can be found on the nLab: [1](https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/differential+cohomology+in+a+cohesive+topos+--+references#higher_lie_theory), [2](https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Higher+Chern-Weil+Derivation+of+AKSZ+Sigma-Models), [3](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+simplicial+manifold#references).

[Čech cocycles for differential characteristic classes – An ∞-Lie theoretic construction](https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Cocycles+for+differential+characteristic+classes) is one of the more accessible introductory articles, though it requires some knowledge of modern homotopy theory.

Comment: Hi... Are there any references that are not in n lab style.. .:D please see if you can suggest some..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: The overwhelming majority of references in the links are not in the nLab style (and are written by people who never contributed to the nLab).  Maybe some of Urs Schreiber's papers are, but even then the style is quite different.

Comment: Thanks you. I will try and respond here.. :)